# $P (x)$ and $Q (x)$ are predicates and $a$ is an element of the domain of the variable $x$

Tags: logic, predicate-logic

$P (x)$ and $Q (x)$ are predicates and $a$ is an element of the domain of the variable $x$.

Assuming that $[∃x (Q (x) → P (x))] ∧ Q (a)$ is true, can we conclude that $P (a)$ is true?

Comment: What are *your* thoughts? Surely, you must have some ideas ... Please add to your Post.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Not necessarily. With the expression $$\exists x: Q(x)\rightarrow P(x)$$ you are indicating that there exists *some* x for which $P(x)\rightarrow Q(x)$ is true.

Then, knowing $Q(a)$ is true isn't enough to imply $P(a)$, since $a$ ***could*** be "one of those $x$s" that satisfy $P(x)\rightarrow Q(x)$, but it could also *not* be part of the set of $x$s that satisfy that. There just isn't enough information to discern which situation we are in.